# Função booleana em C

Tags: c, funções

Exercícios de faculdade.

Galera, resolvi fazer uma função para não precisar ficar escrevendo o mesmo código toda vez que quero saber se o usuário vai continuar ou não o programa.

O que acontece é que parece que toda vez a função retorna como verdadeira e o meu código continua novamente.

Essa foi a função que criei

```
bool continuarCodigo (char escolha, bool continuar){

printf("Deseja continuar o programa? S/N");
scanf("%c", &escolha);
fflush(stdin);
while (escolha != 's' && escolha != 'S' && escolha != 'n' && escolha != 'N'){
    printf("Opcao invalida, digite S/N");
    scanf("%c", &escolha);
    fflush(stdin);
}
if (escolha == 's' || escolha == 'S'){
    continuar = true;
} else if (escolha == 'n' || escolha == 'N'){
    continuar = false;
}

return continuar;
```

Ela chega a entrar no último if para alterar o continuar para false mas o código prossegue do mesmo jeito.

Comment: Adicione o trecho do código que faz a chamada dessa função, por favor.

Comment: Já consegui, muito obrigado pela atenção :)

Answer (score 0):

Problema resolvido, depois de muito quebrar a cabeça em como printar o booleano consegui verificar que ele estava funcionando porém não estava alterando o valor da minha variável na função principal, o que eu fiz foi o seguinte

```
continuar = continuarCodigo(escolha, continuar);
```

Declarei a função dentro da minha variável booleana em meu código, ai funcionou normalmente :)

Comment: Não chame a função dentro dela mesma, isso gera recursão desnecessária e pode dar estouro de pilha (veja mais [aqui](/q/21551/112052), [aqui](/q/107657/112052), [aqui](/q/184494/112052), [aqui](/q/4282/112052) e [aqui](/q/362825/112052)). Enfim, prefira um loop simples. E não use `fflush(stdin)`, apesar de "funcionar" em alguns casos, não é portável e pode não funcionar em todos os ambientes ([leia aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2979209)). Enfim, uma alternativa um pouco melhor seria: https://ideone.com/gEmhC5 - e não deixe de ler [isso](/q/42981/112052)

Comment: Caramba velho, muito obrigado mesmo pela explicação!

Sou iniciante então não entendi muito bem o método de limpar o buffer hehe mas pode deixar que vou estudar para entender o que vc fez

Muito obrigado mesmo :)